# How to pass dictonary and key to a function

Tags: python

I need to pass a dictonary name and a key of same dictonary to a function. That function will return the value of that key from the dictory. Both Dictonary name and key are variables here not sure how to pass them. Cannot do `my_dict['one']` here.

```
def fetch_values(DICT_NAME, DICT_KEY):
    try:
        data = DICT_NAME%s DICT_KEY
    except KeyError:
        print("bad input")
        return 1
    return data


my_dict = {'one' : '1' , 'two' : '2', 'alpha': { 'a' : 'A', 'b': 'B'}}
print(fetch_values(my_dict,'one'))
```

In short how to write `DICT_NAME%s DICT_KEY`

Comment: note that you are passing string `'my_dict'` string instead of dict itself. if you pass dict there, you can normally access dict's value with `DICT_NAME[DICT_KEY]`

Comment: @RandomGuy Can you please tell me how I could fetch `my_dict['alpha']['a']` ? what I would have to pass to the function ? in above example

Comment: This is fundamentally not a sane design.

Comment: I moved to this approach because I am reading a dictionary with lot of data and need to handle keyError for each read.  `dict.get` is not helping much with complex dictionary

Comment: Please ask your *actual question*. Show a small enough example of your data that we can work with it, but complex enough to show the problem. Explain what the function needs to do, and why.

Comment: @monk now your function makes more sense, you aren't passing a `str` object which happens to be the name of the variable referencing the dict in the caller. In this case, your function might accept several values, `def fetch_values(my_dict, *keys):` and then in the function, you'd loop over the keys, so `result = my_dict; for key in keys: result = result[key]` using exception handling as needed... and you'd call it `fetch_values(my_dict, 'alpha', 'a')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , thanks , your idea worked :) if you could add to answer. I should accept it